# Изменение размера изображения Python Django

Tags: python, django

Всем привет. Задача в том, что мне нужно получить файл до сохранения и изменить его под себя, я не совсем понимаю как из памяти достать обЪект, картинку и изменить размер изображения.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import InMemoryUploadedFile
from PIL import Image



def upload_profile(instance, filename):
    #...
    return 'profile_pics/{}/{}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)



class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', 
                              upload_to=upload_profile)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile {self.user.username}'


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def safe_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Comment: я не понял вопроса), функция upload_location должна принимать два параметра, а у вас только один параметр принимает
`def upload_location(instance, filename): pass`

Comment: Хмм...
А где можно про это почитать? Об этом не подумала даже ...
Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, это я понял в итоге. Теперь вопрос состоит в другом, как из памяти достать файл, до того как он сохранился и изменить его , к примеру мое изображение , мне нужно подстроить все пикчи под профиль, а они в итоге в полном размере у меня октрываются, в html е хочу порпавлять так как там будет не очень смотрется, мне нужно именно изменить размер и подкорректировать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот один из способов изменить размер картинки

```
from PIL import Image

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to=upload_profile)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Profile {self.user.username}'

    def save(self):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```